# HttpClient how to do Proxy Connection to bypass geo blocking sites C#

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to connect to a proxy via this piece of code using HttpClient. 
i would like to connect to a proxy strictly using HttpClient, or if unable to. using any c# library as long as the task is achieved.

```
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
       //setup web proxy and credentials
        var webproxy = 
            new WebProxy("94.232.55.98", 8080)//ip and port number
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        };

        handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = webproxy,
            UseProxy = true,
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false
        };

        container = new CookieContainer();
        handler.CookieContainer = container;
        handler.UseCookies = true;
        client = new HttpClient(handler);
        //Query a url and get its contents, but the request was not using any proxy seemingly
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.GetAsync("https://shop.shoprite.com/").Result;
```

Looking at the code i am in need of guidance on how to connect httpclient to a AU proxy, and how to possibly get a proxy with or without credentials and to make it work all together.

I am trying to access a website geo blocked only in Australia that is why im trying to use a proxy.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have retrieved my proxy from this site ( looking at AU proxies ) 
https://free-proxy-list.net/ and i get the first ip and put it on WebProxy, having 8080 as port number as an example [image]

but it doesnt seem to work.

When i am about to request the site, i am having an error like this accessing a site that is geo blocked anywhere else except in australia.

[image]

Comment: You're code looks mostly correct, are you unsure where to get the proxy address from? If so, can you provide more info on what kind of proxy you're trying to use.

Comment: I have edited sir!

Comment: Doesn't that image say port 8080?

Comment: i followed 8080 now its not working still

Comment: I added more information

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is correct, however the host you are trying to connect to is not accessible through the proxy you are trying to use. You can get a more useful error message by altering the last few lines to utilise the `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` method. This will throw an exception if the status code is not 2XX.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
using (var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync("http://shop.shoprite.com/"))
{
    responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    responseMessage.Dump();
}
```